# Set up multiple country-specific stores using different top-level domains in WordPress

Tags: e-commerce

Right now I am running my store ‘Skates Sports’ on the .com domain and selling on multiple currencies using a currency switcher.

I bought a .co.uk domain and wanted to redirect or show the country switcher popup to the user whenever user visits from the UK. Also doing this to manage both country stocks separately.

I also purchased domains for Italy, Europe, France, Netherlands, and other which I plan to use in the future when I am done with .UK setup in a proper way.

I don’t have a very strong SEO right now but I want to do it properly so it won’t affect SEO and also tell me what best practices to achieve this in WordPress.